# How to fix Loop Error, when using nestled If

Tags: vba, outlook

I have written a piece of code, that is meant to check if the value entered is a date or not. That part works fine, but when I added what I thought would have been some validation (such as length of the string entered and if the date was before or today) it becomes an infinite loop that I can not escape.

I have tried the code with out the loop, and it behaves as expected, however when I combine the two the infinite loop returns.

```
'Checks if the value entered is in a 10 digit date format, after today
Do Until IsDate(DateOfJob)
  DateOfJob = InputBox("What is the date the work is to be carried out on ? DD/MM/YYYY")
    If Len(DateOfJob) <> 10 Then
     DateOfJob = "NotEnoughCharacters"
    ElseIf DateOfJob <= Date Then
     DateOfJob = "Today"
    End If
Loop
```

I would have expected that the code would have entered the loop, collected the value DateOfJob, then run the test to see if it was

1. Exactly 10 characters long
2. Before or today's date

At any point, if it did not pass those two tests, the DateOfJob would be give a text value, which would cause the final IsDate test to fail.

However, I feel it is being passed text regardless of what is entered, and therefor failing the test completely.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You are comparing a `String` value (from `InputBox`) to an actual `Date` value - that does not work - you have to convert the string to a date value.

Comment: Really ? Because when I have just

```Do Until IsDate(DateOfJob)
DateOfJob = InputBox("What is the date the work is to be carried out on ? DD/MM/YYYY")
Loop

```
It works fine.

Comment: Don't you mean to loop *while* the input is a date?

Comment: `IsDate` evaluates a `String` to see if it can be converted to a date, it doesnt mean that it is a date variable. use `CDate()` to actually convert it to a date.

Comment: No, I do mean ```Do Until```.

This creates the loop will continue until that the value of ```DateOfJob``` (which is given by the ```InputBox```) is a recognised date format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The length of the input string makes no difference: either you're looking at a date, or you're not: you want the rest of your code to work with the `Date` value, not the `String` representation that the user provided.

See if this works for you:

```
Public Function GetValidDate() As Variant '/Date

    Dim isValid As Boolean
    Do While Not isValid

        Dim userInput As Variant
        userInput = VBA.InputBox(...)

        ' if user cancelled the prompt; we better not prompt again:
        If VarType(userInput) = vbBoolean Then 
            'if we don't assign the result, we yield a Variant/Empty:
            Exit Function
        End If

        If IsDate(userInput) Then
            Dim dateValue As Date
            dateValue = CDate(userInput) '<~ we know it's valid at this point
            isValid = dateValue > VBA.DateTime.Date
        End If

    Loop

    GetValidDate = dateValue

End Function
```

Use:

```
'NOTE: As Date would be a *type mismatch* error if GetValidDate is Variant/Empty.
Dim jobStartDate As Variant 
jobStartDate = GetValidDate
If Not IsDate(jobStartDate) Then Exit Sub
```

Don't trap the user into a loop they can't get out of without providing a valid input value - an `InputBox` has a <kbd>Cancel</kbd> button, and the user will expect it to *cancel* the operation: don't deny them that ability - gracefully handle it instead.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone's input.

I went with Mathieu Guindon solution in the end, and just modified it slightly.
Nice little bit of code he wrote :)

```
Do While Not isValid
  Dim userInput As Variant
    userInput = VBA.InputBox("What is the date the work is to be carried out on ? DD/MM/YYYY")
    ' if user cancelled the prompt; we better not prompt again:
    If VarType(userInput) = vbBoolean Then
      'if we don't assign the result, we yield a Variant/Empty:
      End
    End If

    If IsDate(userInput) Then
      Dim dateValue As Date
      dateValue = CDate(userInput) '<~ we know it's valid at this point
      isValid = dateValue > VBA.DateTime.Date
    End If
  DateOfJob = dateValue
Loop
```